# Why is there pressure to change seemingly neutral words that some consider 'offensive' to their more 'neutral' synonyms?

Tags: sociolinguistics, psycholinguistics, meaning

Clearly, there is now pressure to [stop using words such as whitelist/blacklist (which are now considered racist) and instead replace them with allowlist/denylist](https://www.techspot.com/news/85080-uk-cyber-security-agency-stop-using-racist-blacklist.html); [master/slave terminology in tech is likewise frowned upon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology)); ['Eskimo' people is also an inadvisable way to refer to indigenous circumpolar peoples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo); and so on, and so on.

I am perplexed why is this the case.

One line of argumentation is that due to historical context these words are, per se, offensive. [For example, 'Eskimo' originally meant 'raw meat eaters'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo#Origin).

However, meaning of the words changes. For example, [in Polish, the word 'kobieta' (woman) was originally a slur](https://wiadomosci.gazeta.pl/wiadomosci/1,156046,6962532,Dawne_przeklenstwa_czyli_jak_sie_zmienia_rozumienie.html). However, nowadays few people are even aware of this fact. Former common words for a woman - 'niewiasta', 'białogłowa' - are now considered oldschool and pretentious. But, the way I understand things, if terms can be derogatory purely by their historical meaning (as opposed to their current meaning), as seems to me to be the case with 'Eskimo', then we should say that 'kobieta' is still an offensive term and should be replaced something else. Such a conclusion would seem ridiculous, however.

I used to believe that words are offensive mainly for one reason, and that is that people use these words with the intent to offend. I suppose that no sane person using the 'master'/'slave' terminology in technology actually means to support the practice of slavery. Nor do I believe that people using the words 'whitelist' and 'blacklist' typically mean to declare that white people are superior to black people. Nor that people who say 'Eskimo' do so to offend indigenous circumpolar peoples. Paradoxically, I'd suppose, these words are now slowly becoming offensive only because of the persistence of those who have declared them such and pressure to ban their use.

It can be claimed that words can be offensive purely on account of that there are people who feel offended by the use of these words. But this line of reasoning seems to lead to conclusions difficult to accept, namely that anyone can prohibit anyone from doing anything on account of themselves feeling offended.

'Whitelist' and 'blacklist' seem to be an especially interesting example. I don't know, but I'd wager that the origins of this term have nothing to do with black or white people. Instead - I guess - they originate from cross-cultural black and white symbolism. Humans are, naturally, diurnal animals. For centuries darkness meant one could not see an impending danger. Nighttime was a period when brigands were most likely to attack towns. Overstaying in the forest at night was far more dangerous than being there during the day. And so on, and so on. Unsurprisingly, people started equating 'black' and 'dark' with 'bad' or even 'evil', while 'lightness' means good.

Coincidentally, there was a period of time in the history when people with a very dark skin tone were oppressed by people with a very light skin tone. If this means that we should ban all black and white symbolism - even in cases when it has zero historical connection with the aforementioned opression - then this is a pretty daunting task, since this symbolism is *everywhere*. I'd also guess that for the reasons I outlined this black/white symbolism is actually innate in humans.

I would like to stress that it is not my intention to argue for the use of these words. However, I have to present my reasoning in order to understand why such terms are frowned upon. If I have a bunch of misconceptions in my mind, I need to present them in order to ask where, exactly, is my mistake.

Why are these words frowned upon and why is there pressure to purge the language of such words?

Comment: I would give a bounty to this question but I don't have enough reputation here.
What's recently happening with people? Why are these common words started to be "bad"?

Answer (score 6):

The reason is not about etymology, it is about individual reactions to words. Plainly put, a word is offensive if, when used, a person finds it offensive. If a particular demographic selection of a society finds a word offensive, then you know that if you use that word, you are giving offense. So you adjust your behavior, or don't adjust, depending on how much you care. You may not know at a particular time whether a word is offensive to those that it refers to, so there is often a struggle to keep current. You may not know that "Lapp" is an offensive term used to refer to the Saami people, but once you know that, then continued use of the term is evidence of a desire to demean those people.

The underlying social causes of the offense that words give is, obviously, social, and not linguistic. Whether or not it is reasonable to be offended by words like mandate, manage, whitewash isn't a linguistic question. I have not encountered anyone proposing that "mandate" should be avoided because it is a sexist term (it contains the string *man*), but you can either take note of how people react, or you can ignore how people react, it's your choice.

Comment: I think it is a linguistic issue because I heard language has a prominent effect of how people think. So perhaps these words are offensive *on their own* because their use, on a subconscious level, reinforces racistic behavior.

Comment: That's like saying that it's chemical because chemistry has a profound effect on brain activity. It is sociolinguistic, but not linguistic in a narrower sense. As User6726 says, the factors are social, not linguistic (even if they sometimes include linguistic beliefs, such as the belief that _niggardly_ is connected with racial terms. It wasn't originally,  but some people believe that it was, so it inescapably is now).

Comment: A huge part of the offense potential of most of these "newly offensive" words and expressions is based on pseudo-etymologies. And I would dare say that etymology and pseudo-etymology are linguistic issues. If one was to take offense from, say "negate", assuming that the "neg" in it refers to black people, wouldn't it be proper to remark that "neg" in such word bears no relation to colour ?